# Winning Strategy with Addition to X=0

Tags: proof-verification, problem-solving, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Problem:

Two players play the following game. Initially, X=0. The players take turns adding any number between 1 and 10 (inclusive) to X. The game ends when X reaches 100. The player who reaches 100 wins. Find a winning strategy for one of the players.

This is my solution, which hopefully you can comment on and verify:

If I have 100 and win, then I must have had a number between 90 and 99 on my last turn. On the turn before that, my opponent must have 89 because then we will have a number between 90 and 99 on our last turn. On the turn before that, I want a number between 79 and 88 so that I could force my opponent to have 89 on their turn. On the turn before that, my opponent should have a 78 so that I can get to a number between 79 and 88. On the turn before that, I want a number between 68 and 77 so that I could force my opponent to have a 78 sum on his/her turn. Continuing in this manner,
we see that our opponent must have the sums on his/her turn: 89,78,67,56,45,34,23,12, and 1.
As the winner, I want to be in the following intervals of sums at each of my turns: 90-99,79-88,68-77,57-66,46-55,35-44,24-33,14-22,2-11.
Thus, the winning strategy is to go first and add 1 to X=0. Then, no matter how our opponent plays, we can always choose a number between 1 and 10 to force our opponent to have one of the losing positions above and so I will win...

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct.

Comment: You are correct.  You can always end your turn on 1 + k*11 (after your k+1 turn)  and your opponent can never end his turn on 1 + k*11.  As 100 = 1 + 9*11, you will be able to play that (on your tenth turn) and your opponent never will be able to. [proof by induction:  Your first turn ends on 1 = 1 + 0*11.  If your (k+1) turn ends with 1 + k*11, your opponents turn ends on 1 + k*11 + a where 1<= a <= 10. And you can play 11 - a as 10 >= 11 - a >= 1.  Your k + 2 turn ends with 1 + k*11 + a + 11 -a = 1 + (k+1)11.]

Comment: Yeah, you're correct.

Comment: As a thinking exercise, try to describe the numbers that have no winning strategy, and then suggest that a winning strategy is to move to the nearest number with no winning strategy.

Comment: Incidentally, this is equivalent to the subtraction game with subtraction set $\{1,2,...,10\}$ and heap size $100$. Subtraction games always have a periodic [Nim/Grundy value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Nim-Value.html) sequence, and hence a periodic winning/losing position pattern. Subtraction games with their subtraction sets having the form $\{1,2,...,k\}$ are discussed [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#The_subtraction_game_S.281.2C_2.2C_._._..2C_k.29).

Comment: Maybe you should add your own answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

Yes, you are correct. Also note the links in the comments for further reading about similar games and a systematic way of solving them.